# Avoiding antivirus false-positive detection upon a new release

Tags: release-management, antivirus, false-positive, virus-scanning

We have released a new application recently and every few days we're releasing a new version with some bug fixes.

Do we need to submit all antivirus makers a white-listing request of our new binary every time we release an updated version? We are worried of being quarantined after a new release.

Thank You

Comment: First submit your new binary to a mass detection service and if any antivirus raises a positive, send your binary to the responsible antivirus editor for them to whitelist.